# Understanding MOSFET operating transitions

Tags: circuit-analysis, bias, circuit-theory

I'm trying to conceptually understand the output voltage and the operating condition transitions that the MOSFETs in the circuit below go through as the input voltage is swept from 0 to VDD.

It's not labeled in the circuit but I'll refer to the node between M1 and M2 as \$V_m\$.

[image: circuit and graph]

1. Is it guaranteed that M3 goes into saturation before M2 goes into triode? I think this depends on various things like M3's bias voltage but I'm not sure.
2. Why does the slope of the graph become less steep from the transition of M2 being in saturation to M2 going into triode? I think it's because \$V_m\$ decreases more, which slightly suppresses the magnitude of current increase forced by M1 (since M1's drain-source voltage is now going down much more significantly). So then the output voltage doesn't need to change as much.
3. Shouldn't the labeled output voltage transition point \$V_{b1}+V_{th2}\$ be \$V_{b1}-V_{th2}\$?

Comment: Your diagram is hard to read because its resolution is too low. Please upload a higher resolution image with clearly readable text.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I've updated the post. If it's still hard to read you should be able to see a larger version of the image by clicking on it. Direct link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCCYE.png